# What is the Weissman Score of LZW Compression?

Tags: algorithm, compression, analysis, lossless-compression

[image: Weissman Score Formula]

What is the [Weissman Score](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.2063v1.pdf) of Lempel–Ziv–Welch (**LZW**) for text compression?

I would imagine that the Weissman score is 1.0, since it is already a standard compressor, or am I wrong?

[image: Compression Family Tree]

Comment: You do realize that this metric was created for a TV show and is almost irrelevant in technical world?

Comment: Yes, of course. I still would like to confirm that I am accurate in suggesting that LZW has a 'Weissman score' of 1.0, as its been technically defined.

Comment: Awesome!  I don't think it's a good (candidate) Weismann score though.  So... you're wrong, it's not 1.  IMO.

Comment: I believe you are correct, for a certain value of alpha ;)